# Convert xml request to array in php SoapClient

Tags: php, xml, soap, request, soap-client

I have following xml file that I have to send as request to a Soap service from a SoapClient in php. I used the SoapVar to create array to sending request but the respond node is not present there. Anyone please , can you help me to convert this xml to array to make request to consume the Soap service

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns4:Send xmlns:ns4="hidden" xmlns="Envelope" xmlns:ns2="hidden" xmlns:ns3="hidden">
<ns4:Pack>
<Envelope>
<Header>
<ID>string</ID>
<StringFirst>string</ns2:StringFirst>
</Header>
<Payload xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:SmsMessage">
<ns3:fieldOne>true</ns3:DeliveryReports>
<ns3:fieldTwo xsi:type="ns3:hidden">
<ns3:fieldThree></ns3:ApplicationNumber>
</ns3:fieldTwo>
<ns3:SomeFiled xsi:type="ns3:hidden">
<ns3:number>123</ns3:number>
</ns3:SomeField>
<ns3:Content xsi:type="ns3:hidden">
<ns3:Text>String</ns3:Text>
</ns3:Content>
</Payload>
</Envelope>
</ns4:Pack>
</ns4:Send>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Thank you in advance